# Причастия и прилагательные

Tags: причастия

Всегда интересовал вопрос о разграничении причастий и прилагательных, значения которых тесно переплетены.

---

1)*Спертый велосипед* (разг.) - понятно, что здесь **причастие**. Сразу можем отметить, что признак сопряжён с действием: велосипед, который сперли. Кроме того, мы знаем, что причастие с наречием "очень" не сочетается.

2)*Спертый воздух* (очень душно) - тут сложнее. Сказать "воздух, который сперли/кто-то спер"(то есть надышали), отчего он стал спертым, думаю, можно. Однако к данному слову мы уже можем и "очень" подставить, что говорит о том, что перед нами **прилагательное**, к тому же и синоним легко подбирается - *"несвежий, тяжелый"*.

---

Есть ли методы, позволяющие убрать вариативность? Имеется ли однозначное решение на этот счет?

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146103/discussion-on-question-by-ajgy---); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.